# Jsoup, determine between a timeout and a 404

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to figure out the logic of how to check if a url is 404'ing or if it is timing out. I can't seem to figure it out!

This is what I have so far:

```
while (i < retries){
            try {
                response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
                        .timeout(10000)
                        .execute();
                success = true;
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                success = false;
            }
            System.out.println("Attempt " + i + " " + url);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public int getUrlStatus(){
        if(success){
            int statusCode = response.statusCode();
            return statusCode;
        }else {
            return 404;
        }
    }
```

From what I can understand this will tell me that a page 404's not if a page timesout. How can I check for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch `SocketTimeoutException` when connecting:

```
  try {
                response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
                        .timeout(10000)
                        .execute();
                success = true;
                break;
            } catch (SocketTimeoutExceptione) {
                success = false;
            System.out.println("Timeout occured");
            }
```